# HowTo define the "Auto" Width of the WPF GridView Column in Code?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, wpf-controls

I want to define the "Auto" width of a GridView Column in the code. How can I do that?

```
var grid = (GridView)myListview.View;
grid.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
   Header = "My Header",
   DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("MyBinding"),
   Width = ??? // Auto
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GridViewColumn's Width property is of type double, but according to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.width.aspx) you can set it to Double.NaN ("not a number") to tell it to auto-size.

If you do that, you have to ask for its ActualWidth if you want to know the width it has auto-sized to.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're looking to do the same thing in code for the Width property of a Column of a normal Grid control, use GridLength.Auto.